# Bind window model value to User Control Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a simple user control that has One Dependency Property (the control is the model of itself)

The property is not directly bound to anything inside the user control, but I need to Bind its value to the Model of the window (or user control or whatever) where I put my user control.

If I set manually the User control Property Value, the property is modified correctly so I can assume the dependency property in the user control is working.

If I set the value to the Property binding it to my window model like this

```
<lctrl:InfoIconControl Grid.Row="0" Name="InfoIconTest" IconType="{Binding  Path=IconTypeValue}"/>
```

Where IconTypeValue is a property of the window model, when I set the value of the window model property it does not change inside my user control. I presume I did something wrong but at the moment I have no clue.

Comment: Does IconTypeValue raise PorpertyChanged event? Show IconType declaration.

Comment: What does the `IconTypevalue` property and it's class look like? And what is the `DataContext` of your `InfoIconControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilties come to mind as likely:

1. Your "model" (you mean viewmodel?) does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and/or you're not firing the `PropertyChanged` when `IconTypeValue` changes its value.
2. You've done something like `this.DataContext = this` inside your UserControl and now the Binding is not working because it is looking for the `IconTypeValue` property inside your control, instead of looking for it in the "model".

Solution to option 1 is easy: implement the interface and make sure you fire the event when the property changes.

Solution to option 2 is simply removing any setting of DataContext inside your UserControl, and instead rely on relative Bindings (RelativeSource, ElementName, etc.) in your control's XAML. Or if you gotta set the DataContext of something, do NOT set the UserControl's one. Instead, set the DataContext of a container INSIDE the UserControl.

In your case, since you're using a viewmodel for your UserControl, using it as DataContext makes sense. But if you wanna support binding to the DependencyProperties of your UserControl, you're then gonna have to set your viewmodel as DataContext of something else... For instance, the first Grid in your XAML.

Just name the Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

And set your viewmodel as its DataContext:

```
InfoIconControlModel mModel;
public InfoIconControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mModel = new InfoIconControlModel();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = mModel;  // this.DataContext = mModel; <-- DON'T DO THIS
}
```

After that, the Bindings will begin to work. But you've made another typical mistake: you're only calling `SetIcon` from the CLR setter of your propertty.

```
public InfoIconType IconType
{
    get
    {
        return (InfoIconType)this.GetValue(IconTypeProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(IconTypeProperty, value);
        this.SetIcon();   // <-- This won't work with Binding
    }
}
```

Instead, you must also call it from the DependencyPropertyChanged callback (that you had already defined, on the other hand):

```
/// <summary>
/// Icon Type dependency Property
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    FLD_IconType, typeof(InfoIconType), typeof(InfoIconControl), new PropertyMetadata(InfoIconType.ICPlus, IconTypePropertyChanged));


///<summary>
/// 
///</summary>
private static void IconTypePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InfoIconControl ic = sender as InfoIconControl;
    ic.SetIcon();   // <-- This will work with Binding
}
```

Comment: OK I suspected that, I used option 2, but Just to better understand: If I have a control, very small and specific with 3 properties in binding, usually i made the control model of itself. Now what is the correct practice for Databinding to be sure that the properties of the control bound to its properties work properly and also the control properties exposed for use inside the windows or controls that will use the control are correctly seen and used?

Comment: The single most important advice when creating UserControls would be to not set its DataContext to itself. Doing so prevents other controls to bind correctly to your UserControl's exposed DependencyProperties. Instead, either set the DataContext of another container INSIDE the UserControl (so it doesn't affect the UserControl itself and its DependencyProperties), or not set DataContexts at all and use relative bindings (my personal favourite).

Comment: OK, I've tested the what you propose, but, if I don't set the datacontext for my User control even if I use the ElementName to tell the binding where the properties are, the Properties of the control bound to the control elements attributes do not work. I need to be able to Bind the properties of the control to its elements and I need to be able to bind the value of some of those properties to the elements of the object using my user control, I thought it worked as a "cascade" automatically, but it looks like it is not so.

Comment: Ok I'm probably too dumb to understand where I'm wrong, so I've created a small solution with my User control and a test program, the zip is Here [link]http://1drv.ms/1HrWhka I've created a model for the UC and a model for the window, still, binding the Window Property to the User Control Property does not work. Thanks if you can enlighten me.

Comment: You were not far from the solution, but you made two typical mistakes: 1) You changed the DataContext of your UserControl (invalidating the bindings to its Dependency Properties), and 2) you've only called `SetIcon` on the CLR setter of the `IconType` property... I'll edit my answer to include the solution to those problems, but please edit the question to include the link to your code there.

Comment: That is definitely tricky :) I applied your changes and it worked perfectly, the property changed method empty was a test that did not work so I eliminated just a part of it Thank you for making me understand two things: 1) never use this as model, 2) on user controls set the datacontext to a contained element not the whole control. That is very important thank you again